# Как проверить изменения в тексте

Tags: winforms

Как проверить изменения в textBox при вызове FormClosing? Если документ был изменен то MessageBox спрашивает сохранить или же выйти без сохранения. Уже гугл поломал не смог найти ответа, может не правильно запрос делаю(( 
вот скрин вылез messagebox, до этого сообщения нужно обработать был ли текст изменен (Например: добавлена буква пробел символы и тп), если был изменен то выскакивает это предупреждение[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте устанавливать флаг на событии [TextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) у TextBox'a, а на закрытии формы проверяйте этот флаг.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private bool textChanged;

    public MyForm();
    {
        ...
        textBox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
        Closing += MyForm_Closing;
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(...)
    {
        textChanged = true;
    }

    private void MyForm_Closing(...)
    {
        if (textChanged)
        {
            // показать MessageBox и отреагировать на команду пользователя
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую разобраться))

Comment: Это решение будет давать ложное срабатывание, если пользователь изменит текст А на Б, а потом снова на А.

Comment: @andreycha, в mc (MidnightCommander), npp (Notepad++) и прочем именно так и реализовано )) Так что это, наверное, не так уж и плохой вариант.

Comment: @BOPOH я и не говорил, что он плохой :). Файловые редакторы могут открывать очень большие файлы, да еще и кусками, поэтому, думаю, такое поведение там выбрано как компромиссное. В случае же работы в каком-нибудь 1С, где пользователь открывает документ с двадцатью полями, или какой-то системы, заточенной под оператора, ложные срабатывания ни к чему.

Comment: Хотя похоже, что у меня уже энтерпрайз головного мозга и я за документ принял некоторую сущность с полями, а не текстовый документ. Судя по комментарию, автору именно текст и нужен :).

Answer (score 1):

**UPD.** *Этот текст о способе отслеживаний изменений в целом*

Отслеживание изменений в документе заключается в двух пунктах:

1. Запоминание исходных данных (при открытии формы и загрузке данных)
2. Сравнение исходных данных с актуальными (при закрытии формы)

Оба пункта могут решаться немного по-разному, в зависимости от того, какую цель вы ставите: отслеживать изменения в паре контролов, либо сделать более-менее универсальный механизм, который будет работать и для документа в сотню полей.

Изменения в паре контролов можно отслеживать "в лоб": завести N переменных, в которые будут сохраняться исходные данные. При необходимости узнать, были ли изменения, каждая из переменных будет сравниваться с актуальным значением.

Если же документы большие, либо у вас много подобных форм, то требуется несколько более универсальное решение, которое будет уметь запоминать большое количество исходных данных и сравнивать их с актуальными.

Решение попроще привязано к форме и к контролам: использовать словарь с именами контролов и исходными значениями. Запоминаете исходные значение после загрузке данных, затем при выходе сравниваете актуальные значения: для каждого контрола извлекаем из словаря исходное значение и сравниваем его со значением в контроле.

Решение, не привязанное к формам, требует наличия объекта с данными (POCO/DTO) и некоторого change tracker'а, который будет в точно такой же словарь запоминаете пары "поле - значение", считанные с помощью рефлексии, и уметь сказать, отличается ли запомненный объект от текущего.

Это если вкратце. Некоторые моменты, например, отслеживание изменений вложенных объектов, я опустил.

Код не писал, потому что написать его можно много. Если будут вопросы -- задавайте, обновлю ответ.

Comment: у меня задание написать простой словарь на текстбоксе, не на ричбоксе. Написал что то типа при вызове FormClosing выходит сообщение что типа документ был изменен сохранить ??, две кнопки yes/no обработал их. если да то сохраняет, если нет то закрывает форму. Суть такова мне нужно обработать события текстбокса был он изменен или нет, если не был измене то он молча закрывает форму, если был изменен то выходит сообщение выше описанное))) Буду рад любой идеи

Comment: скрин выложил к вопросу, и дописал

Comment: @Sergey_73 ну тогда вам действительно подойдет вариант с TextChanged и флагом. Пытаться сохранять исходный вариант текста может быть очень неэффективно с т.з. расхода памяти.

Comment: А пример какой нибудь есть? А то не раз не работал с TextChanged

Comment: @Sergey_73 добавил код в ответ Макса Жукова. Да, и два совета: 1) `Application.Exit()` использовать совсем необязательно: если после обработки события вы не выставляете отмену, то форма и так сама закроется, 2) Добавьте в `MessageBox` кнопку `Отмена`, при выборе который форма не будет закрываться (`e.Cancel = true;`).

Comment: спасибо за пример и за совет, буду пробовать. А насчет e.Cansel = true; просто где то прочитал типа форма закрывается а процесс не уничтожается, кто то посоветовал использовать Application.Exit(); Буду придерживаться вашего совета)

Comment: @Sergey_73 если это главная форма приложения, то процесс унижтожается. А если не главная, то зачем выходить из приложения?